# How can I batch convert videos into 4:3?

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I've got about 112 videos, each ~240MB. All of them are in 16:9 and I'd like to change them to 4:3.

What's the most nonresource-intensive and convenient way I can accomplish this without losing any quality?

Comment: I believe Handbrake can do this https://handbrake.fr/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks. Does handbrake keep all the settings on default so the video will remain exactly the same except with the aspect ratio changed?

Comment: You'll need to have a play, it's a while since I used it.

Comment: Handbrake is simply a GUI/wrapper for FFMPEG. You still have to set up the options and configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i <input, use a glob> -vf scale=<resolutionx>x<resolutiony>,setdar=16:9
```

A single command should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Most video converters will *stretch* the image vertically.
You will need to find one that will convert the 16:9 video so it is minimized and
has black borders on top and bottom, or people are going to appear elongated.

For a list of converters, see the article
[Best Free Audio-Video Format Conversion Program](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-audio-video-format-conversion-program.htm).

You will just have to experiment until you find a converter that does it correctly.